# Does a dam invalidate all water downstream of its river for mikveh?

Tags: halacha, technology, mikvah-ritual-bath

One of the requirements for a mikveh is that a body of water may not be artificially redirected or rechanneled.  Does that mean, for example, that an entire river downstream of a dam, either for preventing floods, generating hydroelectric power, or asserting water rights, is invalid for use as a mikveh?

Comment: Please cite that this is one of the requirements

Comment: This is a very interesting issue in way to learn what the possible artificial things are, what is a river, what is a mikveh. Who need spring water and who need mikveh. What is the status of rivers. BTW you certainly know that mikvaot in Jewish community are built.

Comment: Downstream means in the direction the water is flowing.  Upstream means toward the source of the river.  So no, a dam would affect all the water which flows through it, so the river downstream could be invalidated, since a dam no longer makes the river a natural mikveh.  Right?

Comment: Let's take Hoover Dam, for instance.  The Feds can completely shut off the water any time they want to.  However, this has never really been done. But since it could, the dam is still a constructed object, a vessel and therefore is not a valid mikveh.  Since most rivers in the US are dammed for various purposes, that basically means a great many Jewish people are SOL as far as the access to mikveh outside an established community.

Comment: "But since it could, the dam is still a constructed object, a vessel and therefore is not a valid mikveh." How do you know this?